# How to Filter Quantity By Attribute in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, filter

I'm attempting to create a quantity filter based on color, size, or both. When I click the red color, for example, it displays the whole quantity of the red color, but if I press color red and size small, it displays the exact quantity I require. Is there a way to accomplish this?

### This is what I mean.

[image]

When I select a color or a size, the quantity should be displayed. Also, there should not be a duplication of my error, since there are three red colors listed above the image.

## Code

---

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function ControlledRadios() {
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(0);

  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Product A",
      attributes: [
        {
          id: 1,
          color: "Red",
          size: "Small",
          qty: 200,
        },
        {
          id: 2,      
          color: "Red",
          size: "Medium",
          qty: 100,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          color: "Red",
          size: "Large",
          qty: 300,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          color: "Yellow",
          size: "Small",
          qty: 200,
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          color: "Yellow",
          size: "Medium",
          qty: 100,
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          color: "Yellow",
          size: "Large",
          qty: 300,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setQty(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Quantity: {qty}</h1>
      <fieldset value={qty} onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}>
        <h3>Color:</h3>
        {data?.map(({ attributes }) => {
          return attributes.map(({ id, ...rest }) => (
            <>
              <label key={id}>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="schedule-weekly-option"
                  value={rest.qty}
                />
                {rest.color}
              </label>
              <br />
            </>
          ));
        })}
        <h3>Size:</h3>
        {data?.map(({ attributes }) => {
          return attributes.map(({ id, ...rest }) => (
            <>
              <label key={id}>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="schedule-weekly-option"
                  value={rest.qty}
                />
                {rest.size}
              </label>
              <br />
            </>
          ));
        })}
      </fieldset>
    </>
  );
}
```

As seen in the data value, I have multiple color and sizes goes something like this for example `{color: "Red", Size: "Small", qty: 200}` I have multiple red values, so right every red should be added so when I click the Red radio button it should display the quantity **600** because the quantity of all the red will be added. but if I press like color Red and size Small it should display **200**.

**PS:** If possible can u not make duplicate of colors like I did 3 color red and yellow, to make it only 1 Red and 1 Yellow same goes with the size.

If you need anymore clarification you need or explanation please comment down below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew! This should do the trick. The idea is to pass more data to your handleChange handleChange - see how I changed it? I grab the data straight out of the target element, which is not ideal, but works.

I didn't do the filtering for you, good luck with that :) Should be just adding a (granted, a fairly complex) `.filter(...)` to your `.map(...)`.

```js
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  const {useState} = React;

  function ControlledRadios() {
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(0);

    const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product A",
        attributes: [
          {
            id: 1,
            color: "Red",
            size: "Small",
            qty: 200,
          },
          {
            id: 2,      
            color: "Red",
            size: "Medium",
            qty: 100,
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            color: "Red",
            size: "Large",
            qty: 300,
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            color: "Yellow",
            size: "Small",
            qty: 200,
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            color: "Yellow",
            size: "Medium",
            qty: 100,
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            color: "Yellow",
            size: "Large",
            qty: 999,
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

    const handleChange = (event) => {
      const id = event.target.value;
      const targetAttribute = data[0].attributes.find(x => x.id == id);
      if (event.target.name === "schedule-weekly-option-color") {
        let sum = 0;
        data[0].attributes.forEach((a) => {
            if (a.color===targetAttribute.color) {
              sum += a.qty;
            }
        });
        setQty(sum);
      } else {
        let sum = 0;
        data[0].attributes.forEach((a) => {
            if (a.color===targetAttribute.color && a.size===targetAttribute.size) {
              sum += a.qty;
            }
        });
        setQty(sum);
      }
    };

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Quantity: {qty}</h1>
        <fieldset value={qty} onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}>
          <h3>Color:</h3>
          {data.map(({ attributes }) => {
            return attributes.map(a => (
                <label key={a.id}>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="schedule-weekly-option-color"
                    value={a.id}
                  />
                  {a.color}
                </label>
            ));
          })}
          <h3>Size:</h3>
          {data.map(item => {
            return item.attributes.map(a => (
                <label key={a.id}>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="schedule-weekly-option-size"
                    value={a.id}
                  />
                  {a.size}
                </label>
            ));
          })}
        </fieldset>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<ControlledRadios />, document.body);
};
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: BTW, DAMN it is hard to use React inline in these SO inline snippets at the moment!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, this is exactly what I needed